# Como desabilitar o ordenamento da DataTable jquery, sendo ela criada manualmente?

Tags: html, jquery

Tenho uma datatable criada manualmente na View segue código

```
<table id="datatable">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Nome</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr><td>Victor</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Ela é uma data table que utiliza o plugin jquery

Como eu posso fazer para definir o "aaSorting" : [], depois dela ser carregada ?

Segue o código que tento fazer

```
$('#datatable').DataTable({
  "aaSorting" : [],
});
```

Mas não consigo por que a datatable já foi criada, e o .DataTable só serve para inicialização de data tables

Comment: Quando ela é criada? Poste mais detalhes.

Answer (score 1):

Você não consegue alterar as opções depois de inicializado, exceto *destruindo* o componente e reinicializando com novas opções. Veja:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#datatable').DataTable(); // inicializa
   var opts = { "aaSorting": [] }; // insere a opção
   $('#datatable').DataTable().destroy(); // destrói
   $('#datatable').DataTable(opts); // reinicializa com as novas opções
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="datatable">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Nome</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr><td>Victor</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Bilbo</td></tr>
     <tr><td>André</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Caio</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Agora, você tem que inserir no objeto `opts` as opções existentes quando o componente foi iniciado, junto com a nova opção `aaSorting`.

Comment: Ou seja, tenho que ter os dados que tinha na tabela em json para mandar dnv quando ela for reinicializada ?

Comment: Não, os dados já vão estar na tabela.

Comment: hahahahaha que tooooooooop mano !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Vou testar se funcionar você é top

Comment: Você sabe como eu faço para pintar uma linha de uma datatable e aparecer pintado quando eu clicar para imprimir no botão (print) ?

Comment: Não funcionou , aparece que a data table cannot be initialized por que já tem um inicializada ! A minha data table não é inicializada com .DataTable() ela é escrita na mão

Comment: O código da resposta é só um exemplo. Vc deve colocar apenas o código a partir da linha `var opts = { "aaSorting": [] };`.